# Why does `& ~` mean "discard the messages that were matched in the previous line"?

Tags: syslog

In the webpage  [iptables log](https://blog.shadypixel.com/log-iptables-messages-to-a-separate-file-with-rsyslog/)

> Create `/etc/rsyslog.d/iptables.conf` with the following contents:
>
> ```
> :msg, startswith, "iptables: " -/var/log/iptables.log
> & ~
> ```

The second line means discard the messages that were matched in the previous line.
Why does `& ~` mean "discard the messages that were matched in the previous line" in iptables config?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `bash` nor `iptables` (as your question tags originally suggested). This `/etc/rsyslog.d/iptables.conf` is a part of `rsyslogd` config, not `iptables` config.

`&` is a part of syntax that `rsyslog` understands.

It's explained [here](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/actions.html#legacy-description):

> You can have multiple actions for a single selector (or more precisely a single filter of such a selector line). Each action must be on its own line and the line must start with an ampersand (`&`) character and have no filters. An example would be
>
> ```
> *.=crit :omusrmsg:rger
> & root
> & /var/log/critmsgs
> ```
>
> These three lines send critical messages to the user `rger` and `root` and also store them in `/var/log/critmsgs`. Using multiple actions per selector is convenient and also offers a performance benefit.

Then `~` is explained [here](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/actions.html#discard-stop):

> If the discard action is carried out, the received message is immediately discarded. No further processing of it occurs.
>   […]
>   Discard is just the word `stop` with no further parameters:
>
> ```
> stop
> ```
>
> For example,
>
> ```
> *.*   stop
> ```
>
> discards everything (ok, you can achieve the same by not running `rsyslogd` at all…).
>
> Note that in legacy configuration the tilde character `~` can also be used instead of the word `stop`.

In your case matching messages will be logged to the file, then discarded (not processed further).